# Finite Difference Equation with Constant Co-efficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I trying to find tutorials on the topic (Finite Difference Equation with Constant Co-efficient) but I can't get exactly what I want.

The said Difference Equation has a `General Solution` in the form of $$y_n = y_n,_h + y_n,_p$$

Where; $y_n,_h$ is the Homogeneous part of the equation

and  $y_n,_p$ is the Particular solution of the equation

I don't know if there is another name for this topic, if there is, can you please help?

Comment: Look around here for *recurrence-relations* (there is a tag for it), there is a lot of material on them.

Comment: You could also add that tag to your question to gain more attention that you may need.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable textbook is :
"Schaum's outlines" 
"Calculus of finite differences and difference equations"
By Murray R Spiegal